# Get data from web service and bind it into a table layout and display that table layout in a dialog box

Tags: android, grid, tablelayout

I am fetching data from web service and binding it to a custom table layout.. Now i want to show that custom layout on a dialog box. Is there a way to achieve that..?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: In that case you need to create `Custom Dialog` and add your set `Dialog Layout` as your `TableLayout`

Comment: Yes,you can display it in activity and set the theme of that activity as dialog

Answer (score 0):

txt_PendingVoid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        /*
         * AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
         * Dashboard.this);
         * 
         * alertDialog.setTitle("Merchant Staff Void Report");
         * 
         * View view = getLayoutInflater() .inflate(R.layout.lay_grid,
         * null); alertDialog.setView(view);
         */

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);

        alertDialog.setTitle("Merchant Staff Void Report");
        GetVoidReport objvoidreport = new GetVoidReport();
        objvoidreport.CollectVoidReport(con, UserId);
        View view = getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.lay_grid, null);
        alertDialog.setView(view);

        alertDialog.show();

        // alertDialog.show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please accept my answer and add points to it if the answer is useful to you.